# Delete a paragraph by php

Tags: php

How to delete a specific text in php

I have a piece of text like this

```
#EXTINF:4.000000,
abfa9dadab4000213.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:8.333333,
abfa9dadab401o620.ts
#EXTINF:7.033333,
abfa9dadab401o621.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.000000,
```

and i want to remove this part of that text

```
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:8.333333,
abfa9dadab401o620.ts
#EXTINF:7.033333,
abfa9dadab401o621.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
```

Can you tell me how to remove it using PHP. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to rewrite a file

Comment: So delete until first occurrence of `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY`? You need to define what is needed.. Also sharing what you've tried would help the question. Additionally note these aren't paragraphs.